# innerHTML doesn't accept retrieved variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying the example from [ipify](https://www.ipify.org/) to obtain a client IP:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  function getIP(json) {
    document.write("My public IP address is: ", json.ip);
  }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

This works fine.

When I try to add this into my document, nothing appears:

**JS**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var s$ = function(e) {return document.getElementById(e);};

function getIP(json) {
    s$('clientIP').innerHTML = json.ip;
}
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p><label for="clientIP">clientIP</label><span id="clientIP"></span></p>
</div>
```

Looking at the Chrome console, this error appears:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Not sure I understand why the first method works, the second does not.

```html
<div>
  <p><label for="clientIP">clientIP</label><span id="clientIP"></span></p>
</div>
<script type="application/javascript">
  var s$ = function(e) {
    return document.getElementById(e);
  };

  function getIP(json) {
    s$('clientIP').innerHTML = json.ip;
  }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

Running this incognito, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at getIP (VM26:10)
    at api.ipify.org/:1
```

[Full HTML](https://gist.github.com/NorbertKrupa/92f8fefdf8c20f33af90b805fc24cc92)

Comment: Above code works, I have added a code snippet to question.

Comment: To me that error implies that the ipify scrpt didn't load properly and thus never called your callback.

Comment: Your StackOverflow question snippet works so how does your code differ to that?

Comment: Are your `<script>` tags **before** or **after** the rest of the HTML in your document?

Comment: Also, is that the **only** error in your console? There's nothing like *"Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"*?

Comment: @Phil after running incognito, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most like happening because of an ad blocker plugin (such as AdBlock plus). To test this, try running in incognito mode, or try running it in another browser.

To permanently fix it, you can remove the ad blocker extension.

I can't be sure of the exact algorithm that the ad blocker is using, but something in your second snippet is triggering the ad blocker to "think" that it needs to block that content.

Regarding your second question (`cannot set property of null`), that is most likely because the element you are attempting to reference ('clientIP'), has not been rendered yet. This is where something like jQuery comes in very handy, as you can leverage the `document.ready` event. This ensures that your code fires **after** the DOM has completed rendering. The way you have it now (in your second snippet), the DOM isn't guaranteed to be rendered when your code executes. Without jQuery, you can utilize a timeout, however, and do something like this:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var s$ = function(e) {return document.getElementById(e);};

function getIP(json) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        s$('clientIP').innerHTML = json.ip;
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: *uBlock Origin* definitely blocks it

Comment: @Kermit, I'm not 100% sure, but it could be that your DOM element has not been rendered yet. You might try wrapping your function call in a timeout (or get jQuery and use the document.ready function).